# Cannot turn Off Report Pagination on Reporting Services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report services project that I'm rending on Mobile. The display is perfect, except that reporting services 2008 paginates the report into two separate tables for reports with many rows. I'd like to turn this off. According to research I have done, you need to set the report's InteractiveHeight to 0 to disable paging. However, there is no such element in the RDL's xml format. Is there somewhere else that this can be done, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in the Designer:

[image]

This element will only be present if there are non-default values for InteractiveSize:

```
  <Page>
    <InteractiveHeight>0in</InteractiveHeight>
    <InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
```

If you haven't changed these values from default, they won't be in the XML:

```
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
```

So you can add this through the Designer, or update the RDL. However, the element won't be present in all cases, as above, so you'll need to add it if its not present.

Comment: Hi, did this help? Do you have any more questions?

Comment: Works for me.  Note to reader, counterintuitively you have to add the fields for InteractiveHeight and InteractiveWidth to the rdl (XML).

Answer (score 0):

Report height could be set from designer view (valid for VS 2010). Follow below steps:

1. Open properties window of visual studio
2. Select "Report" from drop down
3. Expand option "Interactive Size"
4. Set Height Option to "0in"

[Image explaining steps to follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVBcB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of SSRS, I went to Report->"Report Properties", and set the Height to 20 inches.